# Unexpected token with Knockout 3 and jQuery Templates

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, jquery-templates, knockout-3.0, knockout-templating

My application has one binding that uses `jQuery Templates` plugin to bind Knockout templates. Since upgrading to Knockout `3.x` I started seeing an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to process binding "template: function (){return { name:'tmpl',foreach:$data.children} }"
Message: Unexpected token )
```

The above error doesn't allow my binding to work after upgrading to Knockout ver. `3.x` (e.g. `3.4.0`). With older versions (e.g. `2.1.0`) it works normally.

The error may be caused by some conflict with `jQuery Templates` plugin. Unfortunately, I have to use it in my application.

What could be the cause and the solution?

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.children = ko.observableArray(
    [{}]
  );
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://rniemeyer.github.com/KnockMeOut/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'tmpl', foreach: $data.children }">
</div>

<script id="tmpl" type="text/html">
  <div data-bind="template: { name: 'tmpl', foreach: $data.children, templateOptions: { parentList: $data.children } }">
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a special reason for using jQuery templates instead of the built-in template engine?

Comment: Yes I think there is, the code is part of an application that uses jQuery templates to bind data to view. Without it it won't run: http://jsfiddle.net/piglin/UAcC7/1837/

Comment: Well, jQuery templates look and work completely different from knockout templates. You are trying to use a knockout template with the jQuery template engine. Compare [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-6-using-jquerytmpl-an-external-string-based-template-engine). I still don't think you need the jQuery template engine at all. ("Without it it won't run" is not a very convincing reason.)

Comment: It was used by one of the creators of Knockout in this JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qwgrf/) and I haven't found a solution yet that would allow me to do the same without the dependency

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the empty object inside your empty array. Doesn't make sense to have it there anyways.

```js
var viewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.children = ko.observableArray([]);
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://rniemeyer.github.com/KnockMeOut/Scripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'tmpl', foreach: $data.children }">
</div>

<script id="tmpl" type="text/html">
  <div data-bind="template: { name: 'tmpl', foreach: $data.children, templateOptions: { parentList: $data.children } }">
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: The array is normally full of non-empty elements and the error is same. For the sake of simplicity I added the empty object. The question is what is causing the problem regardless of what's in the array.